# Let typescript know the exact type of a parameter (inferred from generics) in a conditional block

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am inferring a type of one of my function arguments from the other argument through generics:

```
enum StatusCode { ERROR = 411, GENERAL_ERROR = 400 }

interface StatusCodeParams {
    [StatusCode.ERROR]: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    };
    [StatusCode.GENERAL_ERROR]: {};
}


const getMessage = <T extends StatusCode>(statusCode: T, params: StatusCodeParams[T]) => {
    switch (statusCode) {
        case StatusCode.ERROR:
            return `Name '${params.name}' (age: ${params.age}) is invalid`;
        default:
            return `Something went wrong`;
    }
};
```

I was hoping that typescript would determine under the case `StatusCode.ERROR` that `params` is of type `{name: string, age: number}`, but it still thinks `params` is of type `{} | {name: string, age: number}`.

Is there a way to let typescript know the specific type under the conditional?

Comment: Case analysis (e.g., `switch`/`case`) and generics don't play nicely together.  Would [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w86GVm) where we replace generics with a discriminated union of rest tuples meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't narrow the type of generic types within the function body. If you were to inspect the type of `statusCode` inside that case, you'd find that its type was still `T extends StatusCode`.

You can get around that by reassigning the value passed in as an argument to a variable in the function block that's not tied to the generic type, e.g. one with type `StatusCode`, but in doing so you would also lose the connection between your two arguments since they both refer to your generic `T` type.

I'm not sure if there is a way to narrow the type of your `statusCode` argument without breaking its connection to your other argument's type. If there is, I'd certainly be interested to know, but I haven't been able to find or think of anything. However, you do have the option of using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the TypeScript compiler about information it can't figure out on its own.

Type assertions can be dangerous, in that they allow you to circumvent type checking. But at times like this they can be a useful tool, so long as the assumptions underlying any type assertion are well understood so they don't break type safety. In this case, I think you can use them quite safely since you could use them in a way that reflects and essentially re-creates the link between your two arguments' types.

Unfortunately, it's necessary to set this up within each individual `case`, and `let` and `const` functions defined within a `switch` block apply to the entire block. With this approach you'd likely want a separate locally scoped variable (with its own identical type assertion) for each different status code. This is easier to accomplish if you use an `if` block instead.

Something like this:

```js
enum StatusCode { ERROR = 411, GENERAL_ERROR = 400 }

interface StatusCodeParams {
    [StatusCode.ERROR]: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    };
    [StatusCode.GENERAL_ERROR]: {};
}

const getMessage = <T extends StatusCode>(statusCodeArg: T, paramsArg: StatusCodeParams[T]) => {
    const statusCode: StatusCode = statusCodeArg;
    if (statusCode === StatusCode.ERROR) {
        const params = paramsArg as StatusCodeParams[typeof statusCode];
        return `Name '${params.name}' (age: ${params.age}) is invalid`;
    } else {
        return `Something went wrong`;
    }
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQzmAzgYQPYBNhQN5QCiASsQPLFQC8UALAIz0A0UA4oQHIkCCAMgPolylGrQAMYqAF8AsACh5ASxBxgAJwBmCAMa54SVJhwAFBGoQQU+eVFtQA2vuTpswAHRCKAXQBc1uXaBUCAWwH4ocGrKAOYA3DZBtgjRYcGQAEbq8QF2UtmBjojORu7sXMR8gqTefnh58rIKctoYIBFQKXAAssAoKMm4NAA8ACpQwAAeqiBYVk6GrgB8ABQRBi443GrRfiMsAA5mFihbO7BFCyZHlvYjXgCU1Iv+gS1tcFBrxa5+8xuDnwu-1O+Tsig0UFWQJK1CoND+JQ81WIjzwCUSb3ah3MlmoUGxx1OUAQc2hrlMOJQ9jgAE99sAMBCvpdgF5QYk1MBkGoQFAAAYcUJQADkABI8ATLG4QhBgFJhZCBn5xZKUG4BlJHoorMoAG4IAA2iiwfPZ0nGBpQuDROQ5XLAPP5MAwsrgAAsYlAAO6gD5etStaKm9HSBrZIA)

As you can see, the type assertion `as StatusCodeParams[typeof params]` reflects the link between the two arguments in the function definition, where they are typed as `T` and `StatusCodeParams[T]`. Because `T` can't be narrowed within the function body, this approach lets us create essentially a proxy for `T` that can be narrowed, and then re-apply the connection after narrowing it.

The downsides are that it's not automatic, you need the extra local variables, and you'd need to repeat the exact same type assertion within each `if` and `else if` block.